# Javascript: when Regex rule matching spaces(/s), switch case is not picking the corresponding value

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to escape the space from a string. For that I implemented the below regex and it is matching regex rule but it's not taking corresponding switch case.

For example, if i have a string like `test1" test2` it returns `test1"undefinetest2`

```
      var attrRex    = /["\s]/g; 
      var attrMethod = function(match) {
              switch(match) {
                case '"' : return '&quot;';
                case '\s': return '&#160;';
              }
            };
strings.replace(attrRex, attrMethod);
```

Can you please let me know if I am missing some thing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During your switch statement each test is equivalent to a truthy style string comparison. It works for your other characters as they are essentially escaped, etc `\"` becomes `"` . In your case `\s` becomes `s`. Dumb I know.

If you were to test using another regex it would work or more simply just test against a literally space charater `' '`.

Comment: @RameshRaja: In other words: You're comparing strings in the `switch`, it's not a regular expression comparison, and `"\s` is just `"s"`, nothing special.

Comment: Thanks Crowder. Got you :)

Answer (score 0):

And answer is,

```
  var attrRex    = /["\s]/g; 
  var attrMethod = function(match) {
          switch(match) {
            case '"' : return '&quot;';
            case ' ' : return '&#32;';
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function whatever(str){
  return str.replace(/[\/\*\+\^'"%`=,; ]/, function re(m){
    switch(match){
      case '"' : return '&quot;';
      case '%' : return '&#037;';
      case "'": return '&#039;';
      case '\*': return '&#042;';
      case '\+': return '&#043;';
      case ',' : return '&#044;';
      case '\/': return '&#047;';
      case ';' : return '&#059;';
      case '=' : return '&#061;';
      case '\^': return '&#094;';
      case '`' : return '&#096;';
      case ' ': return '&#160;';
    }
  }
}
whatever();
// note that I put in zero's for use with Server Languages
```